# Mongoose: Setting a new array of document references when updating a document

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I keep getting an error whenever I try to set a new array of document references. This causes an error saying: **"Cannot read property '$isMongooseDocumentArray' of undefined";**.
How would I go about updating a document with an array of references to other documents from another schema. I'm trying to replace that array of document references with a new set.

```
Lets say I had this schema with a particular reference:

const userCommandSchema = mongo.Schema({
  objectID: mongo.Schema.ObjectId,
  userID: { type: String, required: true },
  command: { type: String, required: true },
  summary: { type: String },
  isFavourite: { type: Boolean, default: false },
},
{ timestamps: true }
);

const UserCommandSequenceSchema = mongo.Schema({
  objectID: mongo.Schema.ObjectId,
  userID: { type: String, required: true },
  commandSequenceTitle: { type: String, required: true },
  commandSequenceDescription: { type: String, required: false },
  commands: [{ type: mongo.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'UserCommand' }],
},
{ timestamps: true }
);


// How would I go about updating an array of document references?

const arrayOfObjectIDs = [mongo.Types.ObjectId("57d2e31f0098c69c4eefde53"), mongo.Types.ObjectId("57d2e31f0098c69c4eefde57")];

const query = { _id: id };

const update = { $set: {
  commandSequenceTitle,
  commandSequenceDescription,
  commands
},
};

const options = { new: true };

UserCommandModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options)
.exec()
.then(({ _id, commandSequenceTitle, commandSequenceDescription, commands, createdAt, updatedAt }) => {
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, seems I was calling the wrong schema model -_-